# Create Test Cases in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to create a test case for the Customer Contract. But, after setting up the configuration and running ClassGenerator.exe from Acumatica TestSDK, then the Access is denied to the site.

[image]

[image]

Just as a note, I am using TestSDK_18_200_0075_52 Test Framework for Acumatica 2018 R2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrestled with this problem a lot with the new 19R1 SDK.  The generator will create a couple of classes and then the site will lock down.  After going through this with multiple sites, I figured out how to combat this.  After creating a new site, I make a copy of the Web.Config file.  When I get locked out of Acumatica, I do a compare with the current Web.Config and my copy and copy over the differences.  When I try to log into the site, everything appears to work correctly.

Comment: Right, that's also what I do is replace the new web.config with old one as the test framework edits the web.config. But, it is not a good idea to replace the web.config everytime, right?

Comment: Well, hopefully you're using a test instance to generate your class files